# Form data sent dynamically through json to server not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

Script code:

```
function submitdata(){

    alert("hi");
    //var formRequest = JSON.stringify($("#submitdatafrm").serializeArray());


       var test = JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": $('#fname'), 
        "email":$('#email'),

       });
       console.log(test);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: "http://localhost:8080/formdataserver/rest/reqdemo/add",
           data: test ,
           dataType:"text",

           success:successmethod,
           error: function(data,status) {
            alert("Error  "+status);
           }
          });

   }

   function successmethod(data){
    alert("sucess")
   }
```

Html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="submitdatafrm">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md"></div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button"></label>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="javascript:requestdemo();">Request a demo now</a></div>
</div>

</fieldset>
 </form>
```

In the above code when i pass values through json statically(hardcoded values) it is working fine and values are stored in database.but when i pass the values dynamically(dynamic values through form) the values are not passed and showing an error alert message??what is the wrong am doing in the json code??Any help would be Appreciated...

Comment: you can save that dynamic values in a variable. And use that variable.
Giva a try.

Comment: var fname =  $('#fname');
var test = JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": fname, 
        "email":$('#email'),

       });

Comment: @MayurRahul this process is not working ..its not submiting the values at all..

Comment: `"firstName": $('#fname')` - you are not reading the value of the input field here, but are only getting a jQuery object that references the element. You need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to send a whole form:

The following is sufficient to send all values in the form:

```
data: $('#submitdatafrm').serialize()
```

Is there a particular reason you need to send as JSON? This should convert the name/values to JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify($('#submitdatafrm').serialize())
```

Note: You need to ensure your target URL is on the same website to avoid cross-site issues (why do you have an absolute URL?).

Your sample data uses `firstname` but the input is called `fname`, so it may just be a typo, but without server code that is hard to see :)

### Whats in a name?

From your class code I see that the server expects a value of `firstName`, so if you want to simply `serialize` the form you will need to have `name="firstname"` (not `fname`):

```
<input id="fname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">
```

### Test sample needs val():

As `CBroe` mentioned in comment, your sample code is not actually sending the values of the fields, but instead the entire jQuery object. It should have been:

```
 var test = JSON.stringify({
    "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
    "email": $('#email').val(),
 });
```

Comment: the above code is storing null values in database instead of the values entered by the user in the form...and also after submiting the values the text fields(fname and email) are not cleared.

Comment: 1) You need to show your server code as well as the problem may be there. 2) Why would you expect them to be cleared? This is an Ajax call, so you would need to clear them yourself after the submit succeeds. 3) Please show the text of the error you are receiving :)

Comment: server code is working fine when we send hardcoded values example   var test = JSON.stringify({"firstName": "Ramesh","email":"ramesh.suresh@gmail.com"   
       });

but its not working when taken dynamic values..

Comment: There is no difference, *except in the names*. If you show your server code I can check if there is an obvious mistake that would cause it not to match.  (e.g. `fname` vs `firstname`. If not, I have other questions to answer :)

Comment: which server code or class you want me to show??there is a lot of server code...entity class,implementaion class,interface or webservice class??

Comment: Just the action that receives the post (for starters) :) and probably the class of any parameter to that.

Comment: @Table(name="requestdemodetails")
public class RequestDemoDetails {
 private Long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String email;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="Demo_Id")
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 @Column(name="FirstName")
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 @Column(name="EmailId")
 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }